# May problem is savechanges in datagridview from mysql

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save the changes in my datagridview but when I click save button the msgbox showing "Update successful". But in my mysql database no change was made.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Intake

Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim comm As MySqlCommand

Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
Dim dbDataset As New DataTable


Public Sub FilterData(valueToSearch As String)
        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=SOUTHEAST;database=reportingsystem"
            Dim searchquery As String = "Select intDate as 'Date', intTimeStart as 'Time Start', intTimeEnd as 'Time End', intDownTime as 'Down Time', intWaitingTime as 'Waiting Time', intReturn as 'Returns', intTOT as 'Total Operating Time', intTRT as 'Total Running Time', intReportBy as 'Report by', intSupervisedBy as 'Supervised by' FROM reportingsystem.intake WHERE CONCAT(intDate, intTimeStart, intTimeEnd, intDownTime, intWaitingTime, intReturn, intTOT, intTRT) like '%" & valueToSearch & "%'"

        Dim commander As New MySqlCommand(searchquery, conn)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)
        Dim dbDataset As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(dbDataset)

        IntakeDGV.DataSource = dbDataset

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FilterData(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Modify_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Modify.Click


    dgvSave.Enabled = True
    dgvCancel.Enabled = True



End Sub

Private Sub dgvSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvSave.Click

    Dim SaveBtn As String = "Select * FROM reportingsystem.intake"

    Dim commander As New MySqlCommand(SaveBtn, conn)
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    Try
        IntakeDGV.EndEdit()
        Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.Update(table)

        MsgBox("Update successful")

        dgvSave.Enabled = False
        dgvCancel.Enabled = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update failed")
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Um, you create a brand new `DataTable` that has nothing at all in it - not even columns, never mind rows - and then you call `Update` to save changes from it to the database. Why would you expect anything to be saved from an empty `DataTable`?  If you have a `DataTable` that you already populated and edited then use that, not a new, empty `DataTable`. If you don't have such a `DataTable`, you really need to get one, so that's your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Try
    ExtruderDataGrid.EndEdit()
    Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
    adapter.Update(table)

    MsgBox("Update successful")

    dgvSave.Enabled = False
    dgvCancel.Enabled = False
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Update failed")
End Try
```

Comment: Still not working. and may I know where can we use cb?

Comment: Maybe your DataGridView is not bound to your DataTable? A few lines above you set `table = New DataTable`. An empty DataTable have no updates ;-)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. However, I don't know how to change this. :)) I edit my post and put my complete codes.

Comment: Change `adapter.Update(table)` to `adapter.Update(dbDataset)`. And use the `adapter` only for dbDataset and it should work.